# Factory girl multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I know I can give factory girl static data values like this:

```
  factory :post do
    title 'New post'
    number 7
  end
```

But what if I have more than one value for each title and number. What if title is 'New Post', 'Old Post', 'Hello' and number is 7, 8, 9. How would I pass that data to factory girl? Should I use an array or use multiple do end blocks?

Comment: why would title have 3 values? 0o

Comment: @AndreyDeineko It's just an example. You can replace title with name or anything else.

Comment: question is the same - why would you have a set (actually, more then one) of values for an attribute? (metamessage - [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to the rescue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
posts_attrs = [{ title: 'new', number: 6}, { title: 'old' }]

posts_attrs.each do |post_attrs|
  factory :post do
    title post_attrs[:title] || 'default title'
    number post_attrs[:number] || 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to pass values as arguments:

   ```
   factory :post do
     title 'Default Title'
   end

   # create(:post, title: 'Custom Title')
   ```
2. If you want just randomize values then simply:

   ```
   factory :post do
     title {  ['New Post', 'Old Post', 'Hello'].sample }
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For numbers you can use FactoryGirl sequences:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "person#{n}@example.com"
  end
end
```

To generate some random strings there is a gem `Faker`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  end
end
```

Faker can be used to generate random emails, strings, e-commerce items, addresses and lots of other things, see at https://github.com/stympy/faker